# Sidekiq-like queue using java tools?

Tags: java, queue, message-queue, spring-integration, sidekiq

I want to have a work queue that behaves almost exactly like ruby's sidekiq(it doesn't *need* to use Redis, but it can - I just can't use ruby - not even Jruby). Basically I want to be able to create jobs that runs with some parameters and a worker pool executes the jobs. The workers are going to use hibernate to do some work, so I think that Spring integration could make things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Integration has [Redis Queue inbound and outbound channel adapters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/redis.html#redis-queue-inbound-channel-adapter).

The inbound message-driven adapter doesn't currently support concurrency; we [worked around that in Spring XD](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/dirt/integration/redis/RedisMessageBus.java#L563) with a composite adapter that wraps a collection of `RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint`.

Or you could use RabbitMQ; the Spring Integration adapter for it does support concurrency.

**EDIT**

The bus was extracted to a [sub project within that repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/tree/master/spring-xd-messagebus-redis).

Comment: Sidekiq is full framework that gives a lot out of the box, I don't think pointing to spring integration to write stuff for yourself it is some answer, but it is not a good answer. Answer that: there is no such thing should be accepted in that case.

Comment: I didn't steer him in that direction. He specifically asked about SI `I think that Spring integration could make things easier.` Read the headline.

Comment: and `I just can't use ruby`.

Comment: Ok, but still it feels that answer to: "I want to have a work queue that behaves almost exactly like ruby's sidekiq" is not exactly the same as implement it yourself using this libraries. :-)

Comment: @GaryRussell that link with your `RedisMessageBus` implementation in Spring XD is dead now.  I'm very curious to see this code as I'm looking to implement a Java Sidekiq worker that could work alongside our Ruby ones as we migrate most our services to Java.

I didn't see it when I poked around in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/tree/master/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/dirt/integration has it been deprecated?

Comment: The bus was moved to a subproject - see my edit - there is also an [SPI project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/tree/master/spring-xd-messagebus-spi).

Comment: Hi, RedisMessageBus does have `CompositeRedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint` but how does it achieve the mentioned scenario. In my case the only option is to use Redis @GaryRussell

Comment: @GaryRussell, could you point to any sample project that uses RedisMessageBus's CompositeRedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean; the bus uses it internally.

Comment: I am looking for any annotation based sample project which makes use of RedisMessageBus to achieve concurrency in processing the messages received

Comment: There is no such sample; as I said, it's used internally by the bus; if you ask a new question, I can put together a new sample for you; the admins here don't like extended commentary on questions/answers.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Framework has `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. You could use it in your class as follows.

```
@Autowired
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor;
```

ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  has properties needed to be set before it is put to use. PostConstruct will be executed after the dependency injections, so we can set the properities of ThreadPoolExecutor there.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    executor.setCorePoolSize(5); 
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(25);
}
```

Then you can start using executor as follow

```
executor.execute(new EmailtoCustomerTask("zhw@gmail.com"));
```

The only requirement needed to become a task is to implement the Runnable interface.

```
private class EmailtoCustomerTask implements Runnable
```