# Problems with Redis Queue supporting multiple consumers with spring integration

Tags: redis, spring-integration

I am trying to implement a redis queue where messages are LPUSHed and RPOPed. I am using spring-integration support for redis queue with . RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint for push and RedisQueueOutboundChannelAdapter for pop.

In DSL Integration flow, I couldn't find a way to say e.g. RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint should pop a message pass it onto the integration flow for further processing for only a fixed number of messages. E.g. when fixed number of messages value is three. There will be three threads that can consume this message and RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint should not pop more messages as there is no empty slot.

Comment: Your question is not clear - add more explanation.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell, I am talking exactly about this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765756/sidekiq-like-queue-using-java-tools.

I want multiple consumers on same redis queue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765756/sidekiq-like-queue-using-java-tools has answer which solves this.